# xfce not working after apt-get update and upgrade

Tags: 13.04, xfce

I have a machine running on ubuntu 13.04. It was booting with xfce environment.
After running apt-get update and apt-get upgrade and rebooting it, system boots to CLI and asks for login and password. Fortunatelly i got login and password, but that's it. I can't run xfce and the machine is an old 3d printer and it's UI is accessible from the xfce.

When i try:
`startxfce4`
i get:
`X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.`

When i try it with sudo, i get:
`/usr/bin/X: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpciaccess.so.0: invalid ELF header`

same with `startx`

The printer is pretty old and ith project was abandoned, so i don't expect any help from the manufacturer. Reinstalling system is not an option here, as i don't want to lose any data, that might be needed for the printer software.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  Thus the oldest *supported* release of Ubuntu is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  EOL (*end of life*), ESM (*extended security maintenance*) or *development* releases are off-topic her  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/01/28/ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail-end-of-life-reached-on-january-27-2014/

Comment: FYI.   Running `sudo apt update` & `sudo apt upgrade` will **not** have upgraded any Ubuntu software since it reached EOL back in January 2014, so check any updates you did get as they may be the problem, ie. malware etc. given no official updates or security fixes have existed now for years.

Comment: @guiverc ok. how can i check what exactly got updated? i'd gladly update the system too, but first i'd like to get back the machine functionality.

Comment: There are no upgrade paths available for a 13.04 system.  Ubuntu releases are produced in a cycle; 12.10 being the first release in the cycle of 12.10, 13.04, 13.10 and the end of the cycle being the 14.04 LTS release. You system upgraded to the next release (13.10) which was gone when it reached EOL.  LTS releases can use that path (ie. all releases) or jump to the next LTS (ie. skip the non-LTS paths), so your *release-upgrade* path is well gone.  Desktop systems can be re-installed without data loss, but again knowledge of your *ancient* system will be hard to come by.

Comment: Your package system logs will show *deb* packages installed; however enquiries of a *raring* system require a working *raring* box now as if I perform CLI enquiries on my box; I can only get answers as far back as *trusty* (due to ESM of that release).